# Calculate the limit: $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{a^{x}-b^{x}}{x}$

Tags: calculus, analysis, limits, functions, convergence-divergence

> Calculate the limit: $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{a^{x}-b^{x}}{x} \ \ \ \ a,b > 0$$

If I try calculating the limit like that, I will get $\frac{1-1}{0}=\frac{0}{0}$, so I will have to use L'Hôpital:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\ln a\cdot a^{x}- \ln b \cdot b^{x}}{1}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\left(\ln a \cdot a^{x}- \ln b \cdot b^{x}\right)= \ln a - \ln b$$

So this will be the limit then. But I do correctly? Let's say it's alright, what if professor asked me if this is convergent? I don't know because $a,b > 0$ and so they could be $\infty$ too, no? So I cannot really say if it converges or diverges?

Comment: If the sequence/function has a *finite* limit then it is convergent (at that point), isn't it? And yes: it looks like you did correctly.

Comment: @tenepolis if a and b are positive real numbers then $a,b \in (-\infty,\infty)$. Which is a open interval thus $\infty \notin \mathbb{R}$ . thus a, b can't be $\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is correct, but you could also observe that the limit in question *is* $f'(0)$ where $f(x) = a^x - b^x$:

$$ f'(0) = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{a^{h}-b^{h} - (a^0 - b^0)}{h} = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{a^{h}-b^{h}}{h}.$$

Since $f'(x) = \ln(a)a^x - \ln(b)b^x$, $f'(0) = \ln(a)-\ln(b)$.

Since L'Hôpital's rule presupposes the ability to evaluate such derivatives, directly invoking the derivative itself is more direct.

Answer (score 1):

It's correct. Moreover, $a$ and $b$ can't be $\infty$. Since the limit is finite, it converges.